# Remove last 4 chars in a number/string

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet. 
I want to delete the last 4 char in column A of a work sheet.

Here are some examples of the data in column A:
2018-08-09 14:26
2018-08-06 20:55
2018-08-06 09:42

I have made the below code but it runs to long even though there is only about 40 rows in the column.

```
function removeChar() {
  var ss =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lrow = ss.getLastRow();
  var rng = ss.getRange("A:A");
  var data = rng.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i + 1) {
//      data.slice(0,data.length-2);
    (data[i][0]).slice(0, data.length - 2);
  }
  rng.setValues(data); // replace old data with new
}
```

Comment: Your loop will never finish, as you don't count up `i`. Use `i=i+1` or `i++` instead. Also, `string.slice` will return a new string and not modify the current one, so you need to assign that to your data again.

Comment: Note that you are asking to keep only the "yyyy-mm-dd" portion from a `Date` object's toString method. Consider just formatting the Date...

Comment: Hi Tobias K,
Thanks. No it stoped running forever. Can you tell me how I assign the data back again? ( I am pretty new at this).

Comment: @Rugge Hi. I'm looking at older questions that don't seem to have been resolved. How did you get on with your problem? Did you resolve it, or are you still looking for help?